# db.collection не является функцией

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
const express       = require('express');
const bodyParser    = require('body-parser');
const MongoClient   = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const db            = require('./config/db'); 
const app           = express();
const port = 3000;

const answer = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/reg', function(req,res) {
    res.render('reg');
});

MongoClient.connect(db.url, (err,database) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    app.post('/reg', (req, res) => {
        const user = { name: req.body.ima, nick: req.body.nick };
        db.collection('users').insert(user, (err, result) => {
          if (err) { 
            res.send({ 'error': 'An error has occurred' }); 
          } else {
            res.send('Успех!!');
          }
        });
      });
});

app.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
    var task = {question: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]};
    res.render('question', {question: task.question[req.params.id]});
});

app.post('/question/:id', function(req, res) {
    if(req.body.answer == answer[req.params.id]){
        res.render('true');
    } else {
        res.render('false');
    }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('We are live on ' + port);
});
```

При отправке формы в консоль пишет db.collection не является функцией. "mongodb": "^2.2.33"

Comment: У вас db это какой-то конфиг. Скорее всего вы хотели database.db(dbName).collection('users');

Comment: Попробуйте `db.collection` заменить на `database.collection`

Comment: Содержимое `/config/db/index.js` то покажите.